# Can I access elements of a 2D array using pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

For 1D array, I can use array name as a pointer and add offset to it to access each element of the array. Is there something similar for 2D arrays?

I defined a 2D array as follows

```
int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};

int** arrPtr = arr;
```

but I got compiler error for the second line. Shouldn't 2D array have type `int**`?

I came across another thread here:

[C++ Accessing Values at pointer of 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118917/c-accessing-values-at-pointer-of-2d-array)

and saw this:

```
2dArray = new int*[size];
```

Could someone please tell me what `int*[size]` means? (`size` is an `int`, I presume).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: while an array can decay to a pointer, array of array cannot decay to double pointer. Prefer using `std::array` and `std::vector` over C array

Comment: 2d array and pointer to pointer have totally different memory layout. 2d array allocate continuous memory while pointer to pointer can point to noncontinuous memory, so they are not exchangable

Comment: Thanks, it's just sometimes I have to use arrays due to constraints..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multidimensional array defined as yours is is only a single pointer, because the data is encoded in sequence. Therefore, you can do the following:

```
int arr[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
int* arrPtr = (int*)arr;
```

In general, the pointer to the element at `arr[a][b]` can be accessed by `arrPtr + a*bSize + b` where bSize is the size of the first array dimension (in this case three).

Your second question relates to dynamic memory allocation - allocating memory at runtime, instead of defining a fixed amount when the program starts. I recommend reviewing dynamic memory allocation on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) before working with dynamically allocated 2D arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I just realized the syntax of int*[size] isn't an int multiplied by [size], but an array of pointers..

Answer (score 1):

int* array[10] means an array of 10 pointers to integer.

You can access a 2D array with a simple pointer to its first entry and do some maths exploiting the spacial location principle.

```
int array[2][2] = {{1,2}, {3, 4}};
int* p = &array[0][0];
for(int i=0; i<2*2; i++)
   printf("%d ", *(p++));
```

If you have a matrix:

```
 1 2
 3 4
```

in memory it is encoded as 1 2 3 4 sequentially ;)

Comment: @user2465355: here on SO the best thanks is to accept one's answer clicking on the tick here above :P but I'm glad to have been useful