# Why can't I access this uchar array?

Tags: c++

The code:

```
unsigned char data[20][20] = 
  {{50, 50....},
  ....
  ....};

Mat speed(20, 20, data);
```

When I try to access contents in `speed.data`, it says:

Exception thrown at 0x003D2094 in speed tracking.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x32323233.

For example, `std::cout << img.data[0][1];`.

In another file `mat.h`, the definition of `Mat` is:

```
// two-dimensional matrix, type of data is unsigned char
class Mat {
 public:
  Mat(size_t rows_, size_t cols_, void* data_ = nullptr)
      : rows(rows_), cols(cols_), data((unsigned char**)data_) {}
  Mat() : rows(0), cols(0), data(nullptr) {}
  bool empty() const; // return true if data == nullptr
  size_t rows, cols; // the size of the matrix
  unsigned char** data; // the contents of the matrix
};
```

So why can't I access contents in `speed.data`?

Comment: Please post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Access at which index? And where? Same scope where you define data variable? Do you properly cast back to unsigned char in your access code?

Comment: Arrays are NOT pointers and casting (the pointer to the first element of) array to pointer pointing to another type will produce invalid data.

Comment: Think for just a moment, what `0x32` is as a decimal value? Where do we see that? Perhaps in your initialization list? a `char[20][20]` (an array of arrays) is **not** equivalent to pointer-to-pointer-to `char`. Hiding that fact by passing `void*` and hard casting to `char**` doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @WhozCraig Is there any good way to fix it by modifying `class Mat`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work with dynamic multi-dimensional arrays in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917783/how-do-i-work-with-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17000418/2079934 shows an example to correctly index a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you do the incorrect cast assigning `Mat::data = data` because the left side has the type of `unsigned char**` and the right side has the type of `unsigned char (*)[20]`.

Suppose that after such error-prone casting you try to access some array elements via `Mat::data`, for example evaluating `Mat::data[0][1]` (which is a bad idea, of course).

Recall that `Mat::data[0][1] = *(*(Mat::data + 0) + 1)`.

`Mat::data + 0` has the type of `unsigned char**` and value which is equal to the address of the `data` array.

Then `*(Mat::data + 0)` has the type of `unsigned char*` and value which we'll calculate now.

As I can see from the posted crash report, on your machine addresses are 4-byte long. So the first 4 elements of `data` array are treated as the value of `*(Mat::data + 0)`. Then we add 1 (`sizeof(char)`) and get `*(Mat::data + 0) + 1` value. The result in 16-base is equal to 0x32323233. After that we try to read something from this location, which is the actual reason of `SIGSEGV`.

It's better to store the address of the first element of array using `unsigned char*` and use matrix width and height, which are known, to get appropriate matrix elements.

Answer (score 2):

`Mat` expects a flat array, so replace `unsigned char** data` in `class Mat` with `unsigned char*`.

The data at `(x,y)` can be accessed using `data + x * cols + y`.